# Is this a plain Bug or a clever precompiler Trick?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

scrolling through http://git.suckless.org/st/plain/st.c I stumbled upon

```
#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a)[0])
```

I know precompiler magic is hard, and my C aint the best

but it makes me wonder if the parens at the end make sense - shouldn't it be something like

```
#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))
```

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13549823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't really need parenthesis when the operand is a left-side expression instead of a type, so your parenthesis at the second `sizeof` are not needed, as this one doesn't expect a type (because of the trailing `[0]`). This `LEN` macro seems to be used to get the size of a statically defined vector.

For example:

```
int v[10];

LEN(v) will expand to (sizeof(v)/sizeof(v)[0])
```

And `(v)[0]` is the same as `v[0]` so the second sizeof is actually something like `sizeof v[0]` which is valid use of `sizeof` (no parenthesis needed)

A well-known (at least here at Stack Overflow) example of a `sizeof` that doesn't needing parenthesis is:

```
int *v;

v=malloc(10*sizeof *v);
```

To get a dynamically defined 10 element vector. Note that the previous `LEN` macro won't work here.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea one could use sizeof w/o parens, and I've never seen the sizeof pointer notation like this. but everything makes sense when i think of sizeof as an operator and not a function